# FadeIn só nos elementos carrgados por Ajax com append

Tags: jquery, ajax, transição

Eu tenho uma div que contem 12 trabalhos e um botão em baixo (ver mais) que carrega mais 12 trabalhos, o problema é que se eu tentar `$('#wrapperTrabalhos').append(data).hide().fadeIn();` toda a div (`#wrapperTrabalhos`) faz fadeIn, ou seja faz o `hide()` e depois `fadeIn()` e eu só queria que os 12 novos trabalhos carregados é que tivessem esse efeito.

Jquery:

```
var worksLoaded = $('#wrapperTrabalhos a').length;
var projectsToLoad = 12;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Ajax/AjaxSearch.php',
    data:{'from':worksLoaded, 'projectsToAdd': projectsToLoad},
    beforeSend: function() {
        //alert();
    },
    success: function(data) {

        $('#wrapperTrabalhos').append(data).hide().fadeIn(2000);

        var projectsLoaded = $('#wrapperTrabalhos a').length;
        var totalProjects = parseInt($('#wrapperTrabalhos a:last-child').attr('data-totalProjects'));
        if (projectsLoaded === totalProjects) {
            $('#viewMoreBtn').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

AjaxSearch.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['from'], $_GET['projectsToAdd'])) {
$from = $_GET['from'];
$projectsToAdd = $_GET['projectsToAdd'];
$projects = $dataBase->fetchProjectsPagination($from, $projectsToAdd);
$countWork = $from+1;
$totalProjects = count($dataBase->fetchAllProjectsByDisplayOrder());
foreach ($projects as $workSeveralImg) {
    echo '<a href="project.php?name=' .$workSeveralImg->short_name. '" data-count="' .$countWork. '" data-project_id="' .$workSeveralImg->id. '" data-totalProjects="' .$totalProjects. '" id="' .$workSeveralImg->short_name. '" title="' .$workSeveralImg->description. '"><img alt="' .$workSeveralImg->description. '" src="admin/' .$workSeveralImg->image_path. '"><div class="detailsHover"><span>\'' .$workSeveralImg->description. '\'</span><p>' .$workSeveralImg->type. '<br>' .$workSeveralImg->brand. '</p></div><div class="detailsHoverMob"><span>\'' .$workSeveralImg->description. '\'</span><p>' .$workSeveralImg->type. '<br>' .$workSeveralImg->brand. '</p></div></a>';
    $countWork++;
}
}
```

Comment: O que tem nesse data? HTML? texto?

Comment: Vou fazer update à questão para se perceber melhor

Comment: contem mais 12 thumbnails, cada um com uma imagem mais texto (descrição do trabalho etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro converter esse data em elementos do DOM e escondê-los. Só depois fazer o append.
Algo assim:

```
success: function (data) {
    var novoConteudo = $(data).hide();
    $('#wrapperTrabalhos').append(novoConteudo);
    novoConteudo.fadeIn(2000);

    var projectsLoaded = $('#wrapperTrabalhos a').length;
    var totalProjects = parseInt($('#wrapperTrabalhos a:last-child').attr('data-totalProjects'));
    if (projectsLoaded === totalProjects) {
        $('#viewMore').remove();
    }
}
```

Assim nessas 3 primeiras linhas a ordem é:

1. converter em elementos via jQuery e esconder
2. fazer append desses elementos escondidos
3. fazer fadeIn() só desses novos elementos

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Sergio é mesmo isso